# Does JPA allow PrePersist/PreUpdate on Embedded classes in MappedSuperclass?

Tags: java, jpa

I have a `@MappedSuperclass` that contains an `@Embedded` element.  Without using the `@MappedSuperclass` the `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` executes as expected.

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseLocalizedString implements Serializable {

    @Embedded
    private final Audit audit = new Audit();
}
```

So my workaround was to add the `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate`

```java
    /**
     * Workaround since the Embedded PrePersist does not get called.
     */
    @PrePersist
    public void created() {
        audit.setCreatedBy(AuditContext.getUserID());
        audit.setCreatedByName(AuditContext.getUserFullName());
        audit.setCreatedOn(ZonedDateTime.now());
        audit.setLastUpdatedBy(AuditContext.getUserID());
        audit.setLastUpdatedByName(AuditContext.getUserFullName());
        audit.setLastUpdatedOn(ZonedDateTime.now());
    }

    /**
     * Workaround since the Embedded PreUpdate does not get called.
     */
    @PreUpdate
    public void updated() {
        audit.setLastUpdatedBy(AuditContext.getUserID());
        audit.setLastUpdatedByName(AuditContext.getUserFullName());
        audit.setLastUpdatedOn(ZonedDateTime.now());
    }
```

Audit

```
@Embeddable
@Data
public class Audit implements Serializable {

    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private String createdBy;

    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private String createdByName;

    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private ZonedDateTime createdOn;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lastUpdatedBy;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lastUpdatedByName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private ZonedDateTime lastUpdatedOn;

    @PrePersist
    public void created() {
        lastUpdatedBy = createdBy = AuditContext.getUserID();
        lastUpdatedByName = createdByName = AuditContext.getUserFullName();
        lastUpdatedOn = createdOn = ZonedDateTime.now();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void updated() {
        lastUpdatedBy = AuditContext.getUserID();
        lastUpdatedByName = AuditContext.getUserFullName();
        lastUpdatedOn = ZonedDateTime.now();
    }

}
```

In Hibernate, I found that it does not allow PrePersist/PreUpdate on Embedded classes in MappedSuperclass.  *My question is does the JPA spec allow for PrePersist/PreUpdate on Embedded classes in MappedSuperclass?*

Comment: I'm a bit confused, what is your question?

Comment: I got same problem with @Inheritance abstract class entity.

Comment: Thank you for the workaround, and pointing to the [Hibernate "bug"](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13366).  I suppose that whilst the actual question of the JPA spec stands, IMHO, there's no reason why the `@PrePersist/@PreUpdate` special case of an `@Embedded` that happens to be referenced in a superclass shouldn't be honoured when persisting a leaf Entity.  Indeed Hibernate classifies this a bug.